# How to validate password with confirm password [Rails 3.2]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

**How to validate password with confirm password in rails 3.2**

**my code not work**

**you can tell where my error**

I've tried many variations changing the code in the controller.

Password saves but not validated to the password confirm field and password field.

help me please, help me )))

**views**

```
<%= form_for :password, :url => { :action => "change_password" }, :id => @user do |f| %> 
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<%= f.password_field :password %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
<%= f.submit "Save", :class => "button blue" %>
<% end %>
```

**User Controller**

```
  def change_password
    @page_title = "Changing Zetfon account password"
    @user = current_user
    if request.post?

       @user.password = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(params[:password][:password]) 
    if @user.save
        redirect_to :action => 'profile'
        flash[:status] = "Your password was changed. Next time you sign in use your new password."
      else
     flash[:status] = _('Your password not changed')
        render :action => "change_password"
      end
    end
  end
```

**User Model**

```
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  attr_accessible :password_confirmation
  attr_accessor :password
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

add the following line to your model

```
    validates :password, confirmation: true
```

Answer (score 3):

Is it too late to simply use `has_secure_password`? You can learn about it in this RailsCast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1

I'm not sure why you have `if request.post?`. Isn't that already determined by your route?

According to the documentation for `validates_confirmation_of`, I think you might need to add:

```
validates_presence_of :password_confirmation, :if => :password_changed?
```

Here's the documentation:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_confirmation_of

The documentation seems to indicate that you don't need `attr_accessible :password_confirmation` either.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Oh thank you Geoff, that answered, I will check what is wrong